# Message Systems and parameters in OOP?

Tags: c++, message-queue

In the WinAPI, WndProc has lParam and wParam which are longs. This means you generally have to typecast them into the correct type.

I've read that message systems in OOP should not need to cast things and that this is a bad practice. Therefore, in a language like C++, how would a basic message system work, where each message has 2 parameters, or even object pointers, depending on the message, but doing so without typecasting?

Thanks

Comment: It is a called a "message cracker".  Already available in `<windowsx.h>`, have a look-see.  Your best bet is to use a class library that has already done this, there are many available.

Comment: WinAPI and C++ are very different things. In a proper C++ design, you abstract away the message pump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the general case I doubt you can do without *some* typecasting.

However, in C++ level design the typecasting can be mostly be centralized.

Look up visitor pattern.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

The problem with type-casting is that it isn't safe. Boost provides a number of ways to do typecasting in a safe way.

If the data that could be sent in your message system is well-defined, limited to a few possible choices, then one could employ a [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant.html) object. Variants are kind of like type-safe unions that have built-in visitation support.

However, if the set of possible data is more or less arbitrary, then you won't be able to use a `variant`. You still want to preserve type-safety, so that the person receiving the message *cannot* cast it to a different type other than the type that it was originally given with. In that case, [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/any.html) is a good choice. Yes, you still have to use an `any_cast`, but that will fail if it is not of the proper type.